# How to create this type of JSON data from Laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I want this type of JSON data in laravel for multidimensional navigation menu with mysql database structure.
Help me to provide proper database structure and Laravel methods to get collection of data which i want to achieve in the picture.
[example JSON data i want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/893UQ.png)

[image]

--Category.php (Model)

```
public function subCategory(){
       return $this->hasMany('App\Category','p_id');
   }
```

-- web.php

```
Route::get('/testt',function(){
   return App\Category::with('subCategory')
           ->where('p_id',0)
           ->get();
});
```

but this will get only two level multidimensional array, i need to fetch 3 level.
Is it possible by this type of database schema ?
[Dastabase schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAsuG.png)

Comment: Post your code directly not image. It will helpful to professionals  work on your problem .

Comment: "How to create this type of JSON data from Laravel?" – You do it by writing a program which does that. If you have a problem with your program, carefully read the documentation of all the methods, classes, modules, and libraries you are using, write tests for your programs, trace the execution with pen and paper, single-step it in a debugger, then sleep on it, start again from the beginning, sleep on it again, and *then and only then* narrow your problem down to a concise, focused, simple, short, reproducible [mcve] and ask a specific, focused, narrow question on [so].

Comment: It looks like you are fetching data using laravel Realtioship(from picture). If its correct then just return with **return response()->json($result, 200);** . if not then try to use Relationships and fetch. If you will post your code then it will be easy to understand.

Comment: I have added some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have edited the model. Please try this. this will help you.

```
    //Category Model
    public function subCategory()
    {
      return $this->hasOne(Category::class, 'p_id', 'id');
    }
    //Category Model
    public function subChildCategory()
    {
       return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'c_id', 'id');
    }
```

Fetch the datas using

```
$item = Category::with('subCategory.subChildCategory')->where('p_id', false)
        ->get()->toArray();
```

and the table I created is(you can add columns)

```
CREATE TABLE `items` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `c_id` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `p_id` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

//The data  inserted are

```
id  cat_name        c_id   p_id
1   Electronics     null    0
2   Mobile          null    1
3   Samsung          2      1
4   LG               2      1
```

and my result is

```
array:1 [
  0 => array:5 [
   "id" => 1
   "category_name" => "Electronics"
   "c_id" => null
   "p_id" => "0"
   "sub_category" => array:5 [
      "id" => 2
      "category_name" => "Mobile"
      "c_id" => null
      "p_id" => "1"
      "sub_child_category" => array:2 [
         0 => array:4 [
           "id" => 3
           "category_name" => "Samsung"
           "c_id" => "2"
           "p_id" => "1"
        ]
        1 => array:4 [
          "id" => 4
          "category_name" => "LG"
          "c_id" => "2"
         "p_id" => "1"
       ]
     ]
   ]
 ]
]
```

I dont know why peoples downvoted. 
Please try this edited answer

Comment: thank you for your help, i have added database schema, according to your code, it need 3 table for each category, i was trying achieve by just one table.

Comment: It would be helpful if you explain what does '.' in with() method, Thanks.

`Category::with('subCategory.subChildCategory')->where('p_id', false)
        ->get()->toArray();`

Comment: Please mark this answer as correct and please upvote this answer if you satisfied my answer. Thanks
'.' will help you to make nested relationships. 
in your problem, I created two relations on same table and give the matching column carefully. then call the relations in a sequence. if I change the sequence, then the result may change.  once you understand the creating relationships, then the query building is very easy.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a similar array and then use

```
return response()->json($your_array, 200);
```